# How to show available drush commands per module with a drush command?

Tags: drush

For example I would like to see all the commands provided by the [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module, I know I can do

```
drush help | grep features
```

But I don't feel safe doing this with all modules present there (you never know when you miss a command). And it often looses important "second lines" such as the shortcut for features-revert-all.
Do you know any command / technique to make sure you get it all safely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `--filter` feature of Drush. For example, you can use `drush --filter=features` to get all the commands available from the Features module, or `drush --filter=views` to get all the Drush commands available from the Views module.

You could then also pipe that output into a file if you wanted (e.g. `drush --filter=views > views_drush_commands.txt`).

You can find the docs on the [Drush homepage](http://www.drush.ws).

Comment: FYI drush.ws is down at the moment, but if you type `drush help help` then you should get exactly what's on the site :)

Comment: thanks ! i am runnig the 6.x version from git and at the moment it only shows the filtered commands after all of the rest, but its still good enough :)

Comment: after git pull and upgrading PHP it works exactly as advertised, great :)

Comment: Handy! Also, http://drushcommands.com/ is nice too, though incomplete.

Comment: I can't found the --filter option, in wich version of drush this exist?

Answer (score 2):

If the module have less than 4 commands you can't use the `drush --filter=MODULE_NAME` because you will obtain the following message:

```
[error]  The specified command category onlyone does not exist.
```

In this case you can use `drush --filter` and select the number that correspond with *Other commands* (usually at the end of the list).

You can read more about this behavior in: [How to integrate the drush help --filter option with your custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/214326/28275)

Comment: --filter Doesn't work in Drupal 8

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY I have Drupal 8.6.6 and Drush 9.4.0 and is working, I think you need to write an issue in the Drush project page.

Comment: it say "The "--filter" option requires a value." when used without a value (I have drush 9.5.2 and the latest drupal 8)

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY yes you need to use a module name.